# Select language of a web page with django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-templates

I'm developing a multilingual blog and the example code in the django's documentation works for me

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="language">
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
```

This form let the user choose the language they want. But I actually want to put it in the form of links like:
[FR][EN][VI]
How can I implement that in the templates?

Comment: You could set up a url endpoint like `/i18n/setlang/(FR|EN|VI)/` and make it `GET`-able. It's user's choice to choose the language. Don't see any reason to make it `POST`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using jquery:

```
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post" style="display: none" id="change_language_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="language" id="language" />
</form>

{% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
{% for language in languages %}
    <a href="#" lang_code="{{ language.code }}" class="change_language">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</a>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    $('.change_language').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#language').val($(this).attr('lang_code'));
        $('#change_language_form').submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This may work but not What I imagine. Maybe I'm going to develop a view in which I set the language code of the client's session